# How to create a Spraying Effect

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am making  drone animation which includes the drone spraying pesticide on plants so how do i make the spray effect as in spraying a fluid on the plants. Thank You

Comment: Could you post some examples?

Comment: Mutant Bob is right. I think a smoke sim would be best. It is a little tricky to make it act they way you want. I created a preset smoke pack that may help get you started. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23859364/Pollution.zip I would watch some smoke tutorials to get a better understanding of what you have to do.

Answer (score -1):

My instinct is that you either want a particle simulation (for droplets) or a smoke simulation (for a fog).

Neither of these is trivial to pull off.  I can imagine that getting the "smoke" to flow down will require some tweaks.